# Jquery not returning the value of checkbox. But returns ID of checkbox. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am using the below script to show the selected ID of checkbox. Which is working perfectly fine. When tried to get value it dosent return me the value.

```
<div id="selected-ID"></div>   

     function storeID() {
            var ID = $checkboxes.map(function () {
                if (this.checked) return this.id;    //this.value;
            }).get().join(',');
            $('#selected-ID').html(ID);
        }

        $(function () {
            $checkboxes = $('input:checkbox').change(storeID);
        });
```

The problem might be because, all my checkboxes are in treeview and the rendered HTML of checkbox in child node of tree looks like this.

How can I overcome this, and store the ID's in a variable ? Please throw some light.

HTML Rendered for treeview :

```
<div style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;" onclick="OnTreeClick(event)" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctlEsnSearchByServices$ctl05$Tree_Index','tfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f')"><img style="border-width:0;" alt="Collapse Other Services" src="/WebResource.axd?d=_533LbcrYzxclETTqT9E9lbjpoP9iiSVLn9WP908dD96sH9D2JXH4BN8Q2OdATM4TYJU67kfDSnJQpffp_ITMVu3Y839pir-IzEhB41mqu6U8EWb0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></a></td><td class="toggle ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_2"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox"><a style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indext0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctlEsnSearchByServices$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_0 toggle ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_1">Other Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="toggle ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_2"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox"><a style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indext1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctlEsnSearchByServices$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\45bb0a98-ec44-e211-beaf-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_0 toggle ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_1">Mobile Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="toggle ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_2"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox"><a style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indext2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctlEsnSearchByServices$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\9b3dafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_0 toggle ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_1">Hospice Day Care</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="toggle ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_2"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox"><a style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indext3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctlEsnSearchByServices$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\f83dafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_0 toggle ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_1">Website - Disability Information Website</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="toggle ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_2"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox"><a style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indext4" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctlEsnSearchByServices$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\33333333-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_0 toggle ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_1">Information &amp; Referral Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=BOvsSO2B3BKMupOSRxbma89ER-i_r1FrqfnVsgVq_QiVog3IJUebdD29i4BVAo26-lbJh_BLXmsQGU_VArXhNt6ejiWJk87whzKer6ts-_kM9Vt90&amp;t=634604712479085897"></td><td class="toggle ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_2"><input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox"><a style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indext5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctlEsnSearchByServices$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\44444444-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" class="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_0 toggle ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Index_1">Ambulance Service (Non-Emergency)</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

Comment: @epascarello In this case, i am adding the values to div. Expected result when clicking the child node is, the ID of child node should be added to div as '44444444-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039' and for other subsequent click of other child nodes as well

Comment: Would you be able to post an example of a checkbox?

Comment: @Joe I have added the HTML rendered for a treeview. My web page have several Treeviews with different data. This function i try to write is common for all the treeviews in my webpage.I need to store the value (GUID) of any child node of any treeview when clicked. please help

Comment: You have to attach event handlers the treeview way. See the [Treeview with checkboxes](https://github.com/crystal88/jquery.treeview#treeview-with-checkboxes) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no value in the check box
you should add value attribute to the input, and on another matter the input tag isn't closed

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Other Services" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctlEsnSearchByServices_ctl05_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox" />
```